# SFINAE Template implementation outside of the class declaration

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Is there a way to have separate declaration and implementation of a template class that has SFINAE?

The following example, give this error `error C2039: 'method1': is not a member of 'A<T,nullptr>'`:

```
// A.hpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T>* = nullptr>
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;

    void method1();
};


template<typename T, typename> inline
void A<T>::method1()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You have to repeat the type...

Comment: BTW, second template parameter is not a typename, so `template<typename T, typename>` won't match anyway.

Comment: mainly out of curiosity: I dont see how that code can cause that error message. I see clang, gcc and msvc reporting something else. Is the error message from code you did not include here?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I used msvc 2017 FYI.

Comment: hm what I get with msvc is much more descriptive: https://godbolt.org/z/qPzYGsdE4

Comment: I agree. I should have tried it using online compiler instead of what I had locally.

Comment: it was no critisism, I just wonder why the compiler error mentions `A<T,nullptr>` when thats the actual issue.

Comment: If using C++ 17 a static assertion might be a more convenient solution: `template<typename T> class A { static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>); /* ... */ };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition should match the declaration. e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T>* ptr> inline
void A<T, ptr>::method1()
{
}
```